# Not getting context right... why?

Tags: flutter

I started off following the Firebase CodeLab and have since modified it and added to it.  I am trying to use a Snackbar with no success.

```
class ChatScreenState extends State<ChatScreen> {      
   @override
   Widget build(BuildContext context) {
      return new Scaffold(                                                       
         appBar: new AppBar(                                                     
            title: new Text("Teapot"),
            elevation:
               Theme.of(context).platform == TargetPlatform.iOS ? 0.0 : 4.0),
         body: new Container(                                                    
            child: new Column(                                                   
               children: <Widget>[                                               
                  new Flexible(                                                                          
                     // stuff
                  ),
                  new Divider(height: 1.0),                                      
                  new Container(                                                 
                     decoration: new BoxDecoration(color: Theme
                        .of(context).cardColor),
//call --->              child: _buildTextComposer(),                         
                  ),
               ],
            ),              
         ),
      );
   }

   Widget _buildTextComposer() {
      return new IconTheme(                                                      
         data: new IconThemeData(color: Theme.of(context).accentColor),
         child: new Container(                                                   
            margin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 8.0),
            child: new Row(                                                      
               children: <Widget>[                                               
                  new Container(
                     margin: new EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 4.0),
                     child: new IconButton(
                        icon: new Icon(Icons.photo_camera),
                        onPressed: () async {
                           await _ensureLoggedIn();
                           File imageFile = await ImagePicker.pickImage();
                           int random = new Random().nextInt(100000);
                           StorageReference ref =
                           FirebaseStorage.instance.ref().child("image_$random.jpg");
                           StorageUploadTask uploadTask = ref.put(imageFile);
                           Uri downloadUrl = (await uploadTask.future).downloadUrl;
                           _sendMessage(imageUrl: downloadUrl.toString());
//bonk!  --->              Scaffold.of(context).showSnackBar(new SnackBar(
                              content: new Text("Image Sent"),
                           ));
                        }
                     ),
                  ),
                  // more stuff
```

When it tries to showSnackBar about 6 lines from the bottom (see `bonk! --->`) I get an error saying that there is no scaffold in the context.  I am confused about that since _buildTextComposer was invoked (see `call -->`) from inside of a Scaffold (see 4th line).

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a `key` to your `Scaffold`

```
final GlobalKey<ScaffoldState> scaffoldKey = new GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();

return new Scaffold(
      key:scaffoldKey,
.....)
```

Then

```
onPressed: (){
          scaffoldKey.currentState.showSnackBar(snackbar);}
```

I find this better and clean than tracing the context.

Comment: I agree that this is the cleaner way... I'm adopting it as my default pattern.